# How to configure nginx for heroku nodejs web application

Tags: node.js, nginx, heroku

How does one configure nginx for a heroku nodejs web application? I would like to configure nginx such that an IP address is limited to N requests for a given time period. Like the classic "You're doing that too much" message as seen on Reddit.

Thanks,

Charles

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Good starting point : **heroku/heroku-buildpack-nginx**](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nginx)

[What you are looking for is rate-limiting with NGINX, read this for a better understanding](https://www.nginx.com/blog/rate-limiting-nginx/)

[and here you have an example gist: **NGINX reverse proxy with rate limiting**](https://gist.github.com/ipmb/472da2a9071dd87e24d3)

[This is the file of the **heroku-nginx-node-example** that I think you have to add the **limit_req** options](https://github.com/narr/heroku-nginx-node-example/blob/master/config/nginx.conf.erb#L33)

If you need more help, show what you have tried so far and I will edit this answer.

Comment: Thank you so much! I knew to a degree the nginx config but was having trouble finding examples of it being implemented specifically for a heroku cluster